# Add custom letter to timestamp instead of month in shell or perl

Tags: shell, perl, date, datetime

So, I am not a coder but i have to write a shell script that can "call" a timestamp in format [A][21][16][30][4] where A is the Month (A for January, B for February, C for March and so on), 21 is the day, 16 is the hours, 30 is the minutes and 4 are the tenth of a milisecond (0-5). Brackets are only for visualization, so the timestamp should be A2116304

This needs to be either a shell script or a perl code, that is part of a shell script (i need to put this is an existing shell script).

I tried searching for solution, but couldnt find anything useful.

The idea is that i need to append this custom timestamp to a file name, like
FILENAME.TIMESTMAP

Thanks !

Comment: Show us your code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by call? Do you want to _create_ it, or parse an existing one? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I dont have a code so far. I want to append it to a file name, i.e. FILENAME.timestamp

Comment: So you have a filename and a that timestamp and want to concatenate them or what? Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, i need to concatenate the filename and the timestamp.
I apologize if my initial explanation was unlcear, as I am kind of new to all of this.

Comment: Don't you mean that the last digit signifies _tens of seconds_ with a range of (0-5) rather than _tenth of a milisecond_ which would have a range of (0-599999)? Thus having [4] imply 40-49 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that:

- time is *now*,
- time zone is GMT,
- you want a fixed length timestamp,
- the last digit should be *tens of seconds*.

I suggest something like:

```
my ($s, $m, $h, $D, $M) = gmtime;
my $prefix = "snapshot";
my $filename = sprintf "%s.%s%02d%02d%02d%d", 
   $prefix, chr($M+ord "A"), $D, $h, $m, $s/10; 
print $filename, "\n";
```

Output:

```
snapshot.J2612182
```

You can use `localtime` instead of `gmtime` if you don't want to use GMT.

Both `*time` functions take a UNIX timestamp as argument, in case you need something other than *now*.